# $\left |{\prod_{j=1}^{N}\frac{z-a_j}{z+a_j}}\right |\to 1$ when $|z|\to\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $H$ be the right half-plane, $a_1,...,a_N>0$ and define $$B_N(z)=\prod_{j=1}^{N}\dfrac{z-a_j}{z+a_j}\quad (z\in H).$$ I want to prove $|B_N(z)|\to 1$ when $|z|\to\infty$.

I think that maybe each factor of $|B_N(z)|$ should tend to $1$ when $|z|\to\infty$. So, fix $j\in\{1,...,N\}$.

Taking squares $$\dfrac{|z-a_j|^2}{|z+a_j|^2}=\dfrac{(\text{Re }z-a_j)^2+(\text{Im }z)^2}{(\text{Re }z+a_j)^2+(\text{Im }z)^2}=\dfrac{(\text{Re }z)^2-2a_j\text{Re }z+a_j^2+(\text{Im }z)^2}{(\text{Re }z)^2+2a_j\text{Re }z+a_j^2+(\text{Im }z)^2}.$$

And we are supposing $(\text{Re }z)^2+(\text{Im }z)^2\to \infty$. However, I can't see why that quotient tends to $1$. Could anyone give me a hint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the *triangle inequality* (both the direct and the converse version) you can prove that if $a>0$ and $z\neq0$ then
$$
\frac{1-a/|z|}{1+a/|z|}\leq\frac{|1-a/z|}{|1+a/z|}\leq\frac{1+a/|z|}{1-a/|z|}.
$$
Now notice that the term in the center of the inequalities is just $\frac{|z-a|}{|z+a|}$, take limits when $|z|\to+\infty$ and conclude with the *squeeze theorem*.